# cin is being ignored when another cin was previously used

Tags: c++, cin

Have 2 functions - `fill()` and `Sum()`.  When `Sum()` is called after `fill()`, I get `(!cin)`.

I found that when I replace `while (cin>>u){}` with `cin>>u`, there is no problem, but I need to multiply the input.

```
void fill (vector <int>& x){
    int u;
    while (cin>>u){
        x.push_back(u);   
    }
```

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int Sum (std::vector<int>& x){
  std::cout << "Enter number: ";
  int number;
  std::cin >> number; //THIS LINE 
  if (!std::cin){
    throw std::runtime_error (" "); // semicolon was missing before edit
  }
  if(number >= 0 && number < x.size()){
    //doing smthg
  }
  return 0; // was missing before edit.
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Can you edit this into a [mre]?

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: How can the `Sum()` function even compile with a missing semicolon behind the throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this loop finishes

```
while (cin>>u){
    x.push_back(u);   
}
```

it is because `cin>>u` has returned false. When this happens (however it happens, unfortunately you didn't say) `cin` will be in an *error state* and no further input will happen until you clear that error state. This explains what you have observed. Additionally you might need to clear any pending input, but can't say for certain until I understand precisely what input you are giving to your program

Suggest you change the above code to this

```
while (cin>>u){
    x.push_back(u);   
}
cin.clear(); // clear error state
cin.ignore(999, '\n'); // clear pending input
```

Comment: Input should be like this:  1 2 3 4 | (or any other not-integer at the end).
So, thanks, that worked. I probably should learn more before asking such questions.

Comment: @AlexeyVolvak Right, I suspected that it might be like that. Then you do need to use `ignore` so that the `|` is discarded and doesn't mess up your next attempt to read an integer.

Comment: Rather than ignoring 999 character, which is a magic number and will break if a user provides a very long input, you should use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` which disables the limit on the number of characters. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore